# Little or big endian: binary encoding with same code

Tags: go

I have a pure TCP server and my client sends one byte: `1` = little endian encoding, `0` = big endian encoding.

I did something like (only here interesting part)

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
otherIsLittleEndian, err := reader.ReadByte()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var encoding = struct {}{}
if otherIsLittleEndian == 1 {
    encoding = binary.LittleEndian
} else {
    encoding = binary.BigEndian
}
```

and then here's the part that's not working:

```
rnd := rand.Uint64()
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
_ = binary.Write(buf, encoding, rnd)  // not working
```

The last line doesn't work, but if I replace it with the following code, it works but *I don't want to do it for each `Write()` call*:

```
if otherIsLittleEndian == 1 {
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, rnd)
} else {
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, rnd)
}
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the encoding variable as type `binary.ByteOrder`.

```
var encoding binary.ByteOrder
if otherIsLittleEndian == 1 {
    encoding = binary.LittleEndian
} else {
    encoding = binary.BigEndian
}
```

As the error message tells you, the argument to `binary.Write` is a `binary.ByteOrder`, not a `struct{}`.

The `binary.LittleEndian` and `binary.BigEndian` values implement the `binary.ByteOrder` interface ([documentation](https://godoc.org/encoding/binary#pkg-variables)).